# Swift 3 : Fail to write file to Document Directory

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to download a file and write into document directory but when I run on the `simulator`, it returns error like this:

> **Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “logo.jpg” doesn’t exist."**

I write the codes like this and what I am wrong? Thanks.

```
var absPath = "./image/logo.png"
var sourceUrl = "http://www.example.com/data/"
var documentUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL                   
let strIdx = absPath.index(absPath.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)

if (absPath.hasPrefix("./"))
{
   absPath = absPath.substring(from: strIdx)
}

let sourceUrl = URL(string: self.sourceUrl.appending(absPath))
let fileData = try NSData(contentsOf: sourceUrl!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
let destPath = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent(absPath)

do {
  try fileData.write(toFile: destPath.path, options: .atomicWrite)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`absPath` contains a subdirectory. If you want to save the file directly into `Documents` you have to strip the `image` subdirectory.

```
let destPath = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent(sourceUrl!.lastPathComponent)
```

Otherwise you have to create the `image` directory in `Documents`.

---

Note: In Swift 3 don't use `NSData` and it's highly recommended to use the URL related API

```
do {
    let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: sourceUrl!)  
    try fileData.write(to: sourceUrl!, options: .atomic)
...
```